# Bash - Pattern match file extension in case statement

Tags: bash

I'm looking to match a file extension pattern in a Bash case statement.

So far I have tried `/(\.).{3}/:`

```
case ${myArray[count]} in

 *CODE*) $codeFound[count]=${myArray[count]};;
/(\.).{3}/) $extensionFound[count]=${myArray[count]};;

esac
```

The pattern match for CODE works, however I am having trouble with the pattern for file extensions.
The above throws an error:

syntax error near unexpected token `('

If I wrap the RegEx in @() e.g. `@(/(\.).{3}/)`  the pattern isn't matched either.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern matching in a case statement does not use regular expression. From the manpage:

> A case command first expands word, and tries to match it against
>      each pattern in turn, using the same matching rules as for path‐
>      name expansion (see Pathname  Expansion  below).

You will either need to use a block of if statements, or do further regex checking based on a loose glob in the case statement.

```
case ${myArray[count]} in

 *CODE*) 
     $codeFound[count]=${myArray[count]};;
 *.*) 
   if [[ ${myArray[count]} =~ \..{3} ]]; then 
      $extensionFound[count]=${myArray[count]}
   fi;;

esac
```

Comment: @Pumbaa80 That would be a better pattern match for the case statement +1.